Legend symbols (but not text) are present in R ggplot2
I made a complicated figure a while ago that looked like this:

Unfortunately, since that time my computer died and I lost the most recent, functional version of the code I used to generate this figure. I have most of it, however the legend text is not visible despite the legend symbols being present (see below, I have removed the icons to make it easier to read). Can someone help me figure out why the legend text isn't visible without breaking the rest of the code? I am also missing my x-axis label?? If there's a simpler way to achieve the same output I am all ears, I know I'm not the most efficient coder.

library(tidybayes) 
library(ggtext) 
library(grid) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(prismatic)
library(ggnewscale) 
library(dutchmasters)

sal_abundance.1 <- structure(list(MEANS = c(53.02737, 136.56263, 64.93336, 107.23139, 
                               51.8929, 59.82375, 72.38172, 80.82774, 96.72059, 77.10681, 120.15648, 
                               122.13566, 88.86555, 106.58235, 113.11388), CI2.5 = c(44, 129, 
                                                                                     56, 96, 44, 51, 62, 69, 85, 66, 107, 109, 78, 93, 99), CI97.5 = c(63, 
                                                                                                                                                       140, 75, 119, 60, 69, 84, 93, 109, 89, 134, 136, 101, 121, 128
                                                                                     ), factor.salamanders.tree. = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                               2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("B", "H"), class = "factor"), 
                     factor.salamanders.site. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                            1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("C", 
                                                                                                                "M"), class = "factor"), site_plot = structure(1:15, levels = c("Chesterfield_9B", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "Chesterfield_2H", "Chesterfield_4B", "Chesterfield_3H", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "Chesterfield_6B", "Chesterfield_7H", "MacLeish_2B", "MacLeish_1H", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "MacLeish_3H", "MacLeish_4B(M)", "MacLeish_5H", "MacLeish_6H", 
                                                                                                                                                                                "MacLeish_7B", "MacLeish_8H", "MacLeish_9H"), class = "factor"), 
                     site = c("Chesterfield", "Chesterfield", "Chesterfield", 
                              "Chesterfield", "Chesterfield", "Chesterfield", "MacLeish", 
                              "MacLeish", "MacLeish", "MacLeish", "MacLeish", "MacLeish", 
                              "MacLeish", "MacLeish", "MacLeish"), plot_pair = c("Pair 1", 
                                                                                 "Pair 1", "Pair 2", "Pair 2", "Pair 3", "Pair 3", "Pair 1", 
                                                                                 "Pair 1", "Pair 1", "Pair 2", "Pair 2", "Pair 2", "Pair 3", 
                                                                                 "Pair 3", "Pair 3")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

# Some specific colors
Little <- unique(dutchmasters$little_street)

# Create plot labels for each mean point
labels <- c("Plot 9","Plot 2","Plot 4","Plot 3","Plot 6","Plot 7","Plot 2","Plot 1","Plot 3","Plot 4","Plot 5","Plot 6","Plot 7","Plot 8","Plot 9")

# Establish plot theme, width, and font
theme_set(theme_light(base_size = 18, base_family = "Roboto"))



# Generate the plot
t <- ggplot(sal_abundance.1, aes(y = factor(site_plot), 
                                 x = MEANS, xmin = CI2.5, 
                                 xmax = CI97.5, color = factor.salamanders.tree., linetype = factor.salamanders.tree.)) +
# Weirdly the following point intervals will not run unless this one runs first  
geom_pointinterval(position = position_dodge(width = .3), 
                     color = "transparent", 
                     interval_size = 3, 
                     point_size = 3, 
                     linetype = "blank", 
                     show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Means",
    values = c("Site" = "grey30", "*B. lenta*" = clr_saturate(Little[8],shift = .5), "*T. canadensis*" = Little[4])) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = "Means",
    values = c("Site" = 1, "*B. lenta*" = 2, "*T. canadensis*" = 2),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = .8,shape = NA))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 97.54342, y = 15.6, xend = 97.54342, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "Site", linetype = "Site"), alpha = .015, inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 106.5894, y = 15.6, xend = 106.5894, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "*T. canadensis*", linetype = "*T. canadensis*"), alpha = .015, inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 79.45136, y = 15.6, xend = 79.45136, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "*B. lenta*", linetype = "*B. lenta*"), alpha = .015, inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 78.9119, y = 0.4, xend = 78.9119, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "Site", linetype = "Site"), alpha = .015, size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 101.2059, y = 0.4, xend = 101.2059, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "*T. canadensis*", linetype = "*T. canadensis*"), alpha = .015, size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 56.61788, y = 0.4, xend = 56.61788, yend = 6.6, 
                   color = "*B. lenta*", linetype = "*B. lenta*"), alpha = .015, size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  annotate("text", x = c(39.5,40.75), y = c(15.2,6.2), family = "Roboto", size = 6, lineheight = .9,
           label = paste0(c("MacLeish","Chesterfield")), color = "grey30") +
  annotate("text", x = 37, y = c(.7,2.9,4.9,6.9,9.9,12.9), family = "Roboto", size = 4, lineheight = .9,
           label = paste0(rep(c("Pair 1","Pair 2","Pair 3"),2)), color = "grey30") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 6.6, color = "gray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(2.6,4.6,9.6,12.6), color = "gray30", linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Tree Species",
    labels = c("*B. lenta*","*T. canadensis*"),
    values = c(clr_saturate(Little[8],shift = .5), Little[4]),
    aesthetics = c("color","fill")) +
  geom_pointinterval(aes(color = factor.salamanders.tree.), 
                     position = position_dodge(width = .3), 
                     linetype = "solid", interval_size = 3, point_size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .3), 
             size = 3, stroke = 3, color = "white", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor.salamanders.tree.),
             position = position_dodge(width = .3), size = 3, stroke = 3, alpha = .3, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(35,150)) +
  ggtext::geom_richtext(
    aes(label = labels, vjust =-.3,
        color = factor.salamanders.tree.),
        size = 3.5, fill = NA, label.color = NA, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "grey30"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Roboto", size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_markdown(),
    legend.text = element_markdown(size = 12, color = "grey30"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "grey30"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(x = "Mean *P. cinereus* abundance") 
t


It is a bit weird, I tried to save your plot with tiff() and dev.off() and it seems to work.
I did not modify anything about your plot (t), so if you run your code and then run my code below you should find the plot (named test1.tiff) in your working directory.
Maybe the issue was related to the dimensions of the image you were creating? 1100x600 seems to work fine to me (unless I'm missing something)
tiff(paste0(getwd(), "/test1.tiff"), height = 600, width = 1100)

t

dev.off()



You could simplify the chart by replacing the geom_segment()s with geom_vline() and provide the data for those in a simple dataframe, and the face wrap on the site variable as follows:
df_vline <- tribble(
  ~site, ~x, ~color, ~lt,
  "Chesterfield",97.54342, "#dfdfdf", "solid",
  "Chesterfield",106.5894,"#dfdfdf", "dashed",
  "Chesterfield",79.45136,"#dfdfdf","dashed",
  "MacLeish",78.9119,"#dfdfdf","solid",
  "MacLeish",101.2059,"#dfdfdf","dashed",
  "MacLeish",56.61788,"#dfdfdf", "dashed"
)

ggplot(
  data = sal_abundance.1) +
  aes(
    y = site_plot,
    x = MEANS, 
    xmin = CI2.5,
    xmax = CI97.5, 
    color = factor.salamanders.tree., 
    linetype = factor.salamanders.tree.
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~site, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")+
  geom_vline( data = df_vline, aes(xintercept  = x, color = I(color), linetype = I(lt)), 
              alpha = 1, size = 1)  

